# Rebuild lost database in Ruby on Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I have an existing ruby on rails app that was on a VPS. I pulled the app off the VPS but never got the database data backed up. I was looking through the source code and see that there is no `schema.rb` file but I do have all the migration files.

My question is, will there be a way to rebuild the entire database the way it was before?

Answer (score 0):

`rake db:migrate` should give you back the table schema, but you don't get any of the data.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm okay with not having the data but from here, do I need to do anything else to restore the DB?